# Given vector $x=(x_1,...x_n)$ and$ 0<x<1$. Prove that if $x_i+x_j<x_k+x_p$ then $ x_i\times x_j<x_k\times x_p$. ( Or if > then >).

Tags: analysis

It seems so trivial and I am 99.999999% sure it holds. But sometimes most trivial facts are hardest to prove. This isn't text book exercise, I just thought of this. Any help?

When we have common variable etc. $x_1+x_j < x_1+x_p$
We can see that $x_1\times x_j < x_1\times x_p$ is same as $x_j < x_p$. So it holds. Now for the ones where we don't have common variable is harder.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please have a look at [this tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to format mathematics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

False:
$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3} < \frac{1}{100} + \frac{99}{100},$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\times \frac{1}{3} > \frac{1}{100}\times \frac{99}{100}$$